# Set text for macOS floating text screensaver from command line

Tags: macos, screensaver

I've tried a variety of different ways to change the message for the "message" screen saver on macOS 10.10.3.  When I change it through the GUI, at least the following plist file is updated:

```
~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.ScreenSaver.Basic.UUID.plist
```

When I try to update this file as root using:

```
defaults write /Users/myusername/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.ScreenSaver.Basic.UUID.plist MESSAGE "test"
```

or

```
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.ScreenSaver.Basic.UUID.plist
```

after closing the prefs window, when I subsequently re-open the sys prefs and view the screen saver settings, they still show the old settings.

The following command to restart the prefs engine doesn't work either:

```
killall cfprefsd
```

If I modify the above files using defaults without opening the system prefs, then restart, strangely, the screensaver reverts to the default computer name after the restart.

Ultimately I'm trying to enforce a custom screensaver with floating text on all my macOS machines.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I think I figured this out finally by using `defaults`:

```
defaults -currentHost write com.apple.screensaver moduleDict -dict path "/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/Computer Name.saver" moduleName "Computer Name" type 0
defaults -currentHost write com.apple.screensaver.Basic MESSAGE "test4"
killall cfprefsd
```

This needs to be run as the current user. Just need to figure out how to run as root but to apply to all users. Probably a login script will do the trick. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: i know this is old, but i do not see the com.apple.screensaver.Basic file .. has this now gone in later versions ?

Answer (score 2):

this thread is no.1 in Google for "macOS screensaver text" query, so I decided to put my answer here.

Currently (**macOS High Sierra 10.13.5**) if you want to change the text of your "basic" screensaver you have to type:

```
defaults write ${HOME}/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.ScreenSaver.Basic.plist MESSAGE "your message"
```

after that it's necessary to reload:

```
killall cfprefsd
```

after that you can test your changes with running a Screen Saver from a command line:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine
```

For my needs I wrote a small script that inserts a ten-minute time interval in the screen saver (to show how long the break takes). It's here [macOS ScreenSaver Text](https://bitbucket.org/mszymczak/macos-screensaver-text/).

Hope this helps someone. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In *Ventura 13.4.1* I managed to change this message by using the `Computer-Name` key:

```
defaults -currentHost write com.apple.ScreenSaver.Computer-Name MESSAGE "Foobar"
```

Maybe this is due to the company policy. I don't know.

It seems to take effect directly, so no need to kill `cfprefsd` for me.